# Ionic is not recognized in `command prompt`

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

I have installed **Ionic v2** using `npm install -g ionic@alpha`.

Then it has successfully installed. But i cannot use the `ionic` command.

[image: Here i list all the files globally available through NPM]

[image: when i try to run the ionic command i get an error?]

Comment: I think you have updated the Ionic to latest version? @Gandharv Garg

Answer (score 2):

The install progress may not add the path to the `System environment`.

#### Try the following step:

- Navigate to : `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.cmd` Check if the file `ionic.cmd` is existed.
- Open up the System Environment from:
- `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `Advanced system settings` -> Select `Advance` tab
- Click on `Environment Variables...`
- Seek for `Path` variable in the `System variables` section.
- Double click and add the path `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.cmd` at the end of that string.
- `OK` -> `OK` -> `OK`
- Restart the command line and try again with `ionic` command.